# Is it correct to say "We did a make"?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, word-usage, software

When we build software using [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or a similar build tool, is it correct to say "We did a make"? Also, do we need to say "The files were built using make" instead of "The files were made"?

Comment: "We did a *make*" and "The files were *made*" are both correct, acceptable and understandable **within the context** of using 'Make', or building object/executable files by any other method. This verb has been in use already.

Comment: Your bolded words are precisely why I added the relevant tag when writing the question. I intended this to be used within context.

Comment: And if the make produces a working program, you can say "We made it!"

Comment: If writing a serious report or paper on the matter I would italicise *Make* or *made*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This *make* is **verb** that has almost nothing to do with the common English verb *make*, except that it has a similar meaning, but in a specific context.
- The application software 'Make' is named eponymously, it "makes" files in the above **contextual sense**.

From *[GNU Make](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html)*, Free Software Foundation:

> A file "**can be made**" if it is mentioned explicitly in the 'makefile' as a target or a dependency, or if an implicit rule can be recursively found for how to **make** it.
>   …
>   … if any source file has been recompiled, all the object files, whether newly **made** or saved from previous compilations, must be linked together to produce the new executable editor.

The developers of 'Make' use the verb in the present and past tense in the special meaning of building executables from object files which in turn are compiled from source files.

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_file)

> 'Make' will then implicitly determine how to **make** all the object files and look for changes in all the source files.

[Rehman](http://books.google.com/books?id=1velOihOTIwC&pg=PA59&dq=%22make%20executables%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UWEZU5ijLoWkigfr7IDICA&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBA)

> Either you compile many files into object files and then link them together into an application or **make** executables with the same name as the source code file.

[GitHub](https://github.com/marcusmoller/pyorpg-client/issues/5)

> *Create an easy way to **make** executables using py2exe and/or py2app.*

Comment: I really like the extensive references. My day is made!

Answer (score 0):

As the past tense of *make*(1), *made* is not unheard of, but because the phrase "made *y* do *x*" is also a common construction of English, "made the software" or "made the application" may cause a parse error in humans and require them to reread the sentence.

With *build*, another transitive verb used as the action for compiling a program, it's common to say "Do/did a build (of the application)"; *build* and *make* are both transitive, so it will seem incorrect if you use them without an object. Although, really, in most cases I would just say *compiled* unless that was somehow profoundly unsuitable for the process.